# Pure CSS Buttons

Tags: html, css

Could anyone show me some tutorials that make a button in css and doesn't require images? I googled it but everything involved images...

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the button to look like?  There is a `<button>` tag in HTML that doesn't require images.

Comment: I guess your version of Google doesn't work. Mine returned numerous links: http://www.google.ca/search?q=css+button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make an arbitrary element look like a button?

Well ... *just* write CSS accordingly! Here's a kickoff example which makes a link look like a button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 3489881</title>
        <style>
            a.button {
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 0 2px;
                background: lightgray;
                border: 2px outset lightgray;
                cursor: default;
            }
            a.button:active {
                border-style: inset;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a class="button">link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: with a little tinkering this can do exaclly what I want thanks

Answer (score 4):

Um, define "button"? If you just want a basic button, you don't even need CSS, just use an HTML input or button tag...

```
<input type="button" value="Press me!" />
```

or

```
<button>Press me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is kind of dull but gets the trick done!

```
h1 {
    font-family: Arial;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2 5px;
    background: lightgray;
    border: 5px outset lightgray;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
}
a:hover {
    background: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.button{
     background-color: #000;
     color: #FF6600;
     font: bolder 1.0em Tahoma;
     border: 1px solid Yellow;
     padding: 2px;
}
.button:hover{
    border: 1px solid Red;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="Button"/>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Another"/>
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/eD9sf/

Answer (score 0):

There are some awesome examples here - [Pure CSS Buttons](http://pythoughts.com/pure-css-buttons/) - of buttons that don't need any images but are legit. I think that you could add some gradients to some of them, but otherwise they looks exactly like the ones on Facebook, Twitter, Wordpress, etc. If you don't know much CSS, I'd suggest that you just copy one of those examples.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple design, but looks pretty good

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
  
  background-color: #888;
  border-top: 0px solid #fff; /*define the color of the upper border */
  border-bottom: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.button:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px 100px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); /* light overlay */
}
.button:active {
    border-top-width: 2px; /* add this so it gets 'pushed down' */
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
.button a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .2rem;
}

/* Second button */
.button-link {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .2rem;
  
  background-color: #888;
  border-top: 0px solid #fff; /*define the color of the upper border */
  border-bottom: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.button-link:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px 100px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); /* light overlay */
}
.button-link:active {
    border-top-width: 2px; /* add this so it gets 'pushed down' */
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"><a href="#">Click me</a></div><br/>
<a class="button-link" href="#">Click me, link only</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one looks lovely, acording to me :)

```
.button {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(61, 51, 119, 1);
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 9px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px rgba(31, 36, 78, 1), 0px 9px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    width: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
.button:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(31, 36, 78, 1), 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    top: 6px;
    transform: scale(0.9) translateY(3px);
}

<input class = 'button' type = 'button' value = 'Click' />
```